# Replacement for Content elements? (Migrating a site from EE2 to EE3)

Tags: content-elements

I've been preparing the move to EE3 for quite some time. The official "[push](https://expressionengine.com/blog/expressionengine-2-retirement-date)" has made me speed up the preparations. I'm using content elements and would really love to keep using it in EE3. It's currently not available for EE3, so I'm really looking for a replacement.

Anyone with a similar situation? Is there a fieldtype I can migrate to?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is [Bloqs](https://eebloqs.com) - the EE3 version of an EE2 addon called [Blocks](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/blocks)

It is a well supported, stable add-on doing the similar things to Content Elements.  There is a migration path from Blocks EE2 to Bloqs EE3, but I don't know how easy it is to migrate from Content Elements to Blocks/Bloqs, so might be worth checking on that.